# Array push with Variable(name) to a Variable(array)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
var abcd=[],efgh=[],ijkl=[],mnop=[];
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('name').push($(this).attr('value')); //it's not working
    abcd.push($(this).attr('value')); //it's working
});
```

`$(this).attr('name')` will return `abcd`, but that `push()` isn't working.

Why? Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: `var abcd[],efgh[],ijkl[],mnop[];` That's not valid syntax... also, `attr` returns a string, you can't `push` to a string...

Comment: @sandeep, push only works on array and `attr` function returns string not an array. you need to make your question more clear.

Comment: `var abcd[]="",efgh[]="",ijkl[]="",mnop[]="";` still not valid syntax

Comment: `var abcd = []` this is how create arrays in javascript

Comment: sorry, question asked wrongly. please check now, help please..

Comment: OK, now that you've fixed the horrendous syntax errors, your only error remaining is what the first two comments have suggested - `$(this).attr('name')` returns a **String** ... and **String** has no **push** method

Comment: If `abcd` is `global variable`, try `window[$(this).attr('name')].push($(this).attr('value'));`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to concatenate the strings. Change this:

```
$(this).attr('name').push($(this).attr('value'));
```

to this:

```
var newName = $(this).attr('name') + ' ' + $(this).attr('value');
$(this).attr('name', newName);
```

As mentioned in the comments, `push` is for arrays, and `attr` returns a string. So you need to concatenate the values manually and set it using `attr` method again.